# Centre of mass of particles in different dimensions

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, spacetime-dimensions

Can we find the centre of mass of a particle in 4 dimensions?
Can we find it in more than four dimensions?

Comment: So how do we exactly calculate it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and the calculations are the same as in three dimensions. You simply take the pondered average with the masses as weights.